# How to wrap the default tooltip(title) when the text is very long?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, title

I want to wrap the default title(tool tip) property if the content is very long (ex. 300px ) it need to show the next line, The content also is showing dynamically , so putting \n is the not good option in my case.

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>
  <p title="This is a very  text that  needs to wrap. The content is dynamic so \n is not good option">
    This is a very  text that  needs to wrap .  The content is dynamic so \n is not good option
  </p>
  <p title="Short text">
    short text to check
  </p>
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use width and height in convenient size then use CSS like this in parent:

```
width: ...;
height: ...;
word-break: break-word;
//overflow-y: scroll;(optional)
```